# Faster way to insert into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently using this method to bulk insert into SQL Server:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
@event.listens_for(engine, "before_cursor_execute")
def receive_before_cursor_execute(
       conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany
        ):
            if executemany:
                cursor.fast_executemany = True

df1_compute.to_sql('timeseries_1', engine, if_exists="replace", index=True)
```

This takes 22 seconds to insert 800k lines. But I think the speed is still not fast enough. Is it already the fastest way to bulk insert to SQL Server? Previously, by doing right click and import files with SQL Server Management Studio. It seems I achieve even faster speed

Comment: Have you tried [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) yet?

Comment: @Otter oh... I haven't, thanks for your suggestion. Did you find some example code that conveniently trigger copy data from dataframe into sql server using bcp?

Comment: This is more of an opinion based question as there are many ways to do what is needed but as for the bcp route, you could try [this article](https://pypi.org/project/bcpy/) that uses the ```bcpy``` package.

Comment: @Otter, I will try it! Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's already pretty fast, as far as I'm concerned. Maybe saving everything to a CSV and doing a Bulk Insert would be faster. Also, there's also `cursor.fast_executemany = True`. Check out the link below for some other ideas.

https://leblancfg.com/benchmarks_writing_pandas_dataframe_SQL_Server.html